# Typo3 8.7.x cloud not acces remote ressource http://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz

Tags: typo3-8.7.x

we cannot update our extension list on typo3 8.7.x on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
there is no error message in apache error.log, an we cannot see any reason for this.

do you have any hints for us?

regards[image: error message]

Comment: still need help . where can I find detailed information about this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after updating /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini 
with a new cacert file 
openssl.cafile= /etc/php/7.2/apache2/cacert.pem

its working.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['HTTP']['verify'] = 0;
```

to `typo3conf/AdditionConfiguration.php` solved it for me.